# How to address the URL of an ashx file

Tags: url, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, project, ashx

I have successfully added a file, X.ashx and its components (.cs, and so forth) to a project.

The structure is like this:

Solution Z

Project Y

Folder Layouts

Subfolder also named Y

X.ashx

```
SO the website has an address http://generic/SitePages/Home.aspx for the main file

I would think that one would use something like

http://generic/Y/Layouts/Y/x.ashx as the URL
```

and I've tried various permutations,

but I cannot get it to work correctly.

Does anyone know how the folder structure maps to a URL?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and this is for a SharePoint project.

Also, my particular project does NOT have a web.config due to the template used....

Does anyone know of a good downloadable project/template for this in VS2012.  I've tried searching but most projects do not have such a template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you deployed the .ashx file to the layouts folder in the 14 hive, then it should be this:

```
http://yourdomain/SitePages/_layouts/Y/x.ashx
```

or

```
http://yourdomain/_layouts/Y/x.ashx
```

The Layouts folder gets referenced as _layouts in the url

Comment: I had noticed that change in case and extra underscore -- not sure why it exists but thanks for the response!  I'll see if this works for me.

Comment: For whatever reason, neither of those options work for me, but thanks for answering.  Does anyone have an alternative formation?  Are these pages supposed to show up in  "All Site Content" on the SharePoint web site?  For me, they do not show up there, nor in any search using "Search this site" ...

Comment: see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456362/downloadable-project-template-for-sharepoint-projects-with-ashx-handlers-in-vs2

Comment: This works but one has to change a property of the .ashx file itself:  change Copy to Output Diretory property to Copy always.  I currently have build action set to compile.  The URL now works, but my .ashx has other problems independent of the URL, so I'm not out of the woods yet.  David, if you can edit your answer to include this property stuff, it may be more clear to any other readers who see this.  Also, if you know advanced hints about these properties please feel free to share them.  Thanks!